# loading component to dynamically generated templates

Tags: angular

i am trying to load component dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver

here is my code

```
import {Component, ComponentRef, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver,
        ViewChild, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MyDynamicComponent} from './mycomponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: '<template #Component1></template>'
})
export class Home implements AfterViewInit {

private componentReference: ComponentRef<any>;

@ViewChild('Component1', { read: ViewContainerRef })
private dynamicTarget: ViewContainerRef;


  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
 let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyDynamicComponent);
  this.componentReference = this.dynamicTarget.createComponent(componentFactory);


   }
```

this code is working fine 
But in my actual implementation the `<template #Component1></template>` will be generated dynamically in that case it is not working because the template id is not yet generated when it trying to load the component. is there any way to use the @viewChild after finish generating of the dom. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information about how you're creating `<template></template>` dynamically (ideally plunker) and what you have tried to do it working

Comment: i am rendering those snippet with incremental id using jquery. on ngAfterViewInit() and i would like to know is there any way to do  generate below code in a for lop
 @ViewChild('component1', { read: ViewContainerRef }) Component1: ViewContainerRef;
i cant hardcode this since  there will n number of container

Comment: Check my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/i92kerVLuNZH7Ait4XIu?p=info Maybe it's what you want

Comment: that was really helpful. will try to implement in this way this method doest require @viewChild. that was my biggest problem.. thumps up for that..

Comment: You can take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115072/how-to-load-component-dynamically-using-component-name-in-angular2

Comment: thanks a lot.. you are genius :)

Comment: @yurzui by using this i have built a component. im using angular cli to build my project. after building this app is not working because the component name what i m loading is not present in the resolver[_factories] it got changed after the build..how to solve this problem ? really need your help

Comment: See my update here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528592/ng2-dynamically-creating-a-component-based-on-a-template/40662376#40662376

Comment: Hi @yurzui i have updated @angular/core to 2.4.3 after that 
this.appRef['registerChangeDetector'](componentFactory.changeDetectorRef)
this line of code is not working it throwing error : registerChangeDetector is not a function. in the latest ApplicationRef  there is no way to register a changedetector. any other way to do this ?
i tried doing the change detection inside the component. still UI is not updating.

Comment: Solved this. latest version no need to register registerChangeDetector. directly  we can call changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()