# No component factory found for component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I know a lot of similar questions have been asked, and i've been searching for quite a while now to try every possible solution, and it still doesn't work. Most of the solutions involve adding `entryComponent` or adding it to the `entryComponent` of the component itself *(bad practise)* but both didn't help.

So i've been trying to implant the same technique as here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGzoPTCHlXKWrn4p8gd1?p=preview).

My code:

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ****
    ArtworkWrapperComponent, 
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ***
  ],
  entryComponents: [TestComponent],
  providers: [Animations, PageNameService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So `TestComponent` is what i'm trying to display based on Input value, this is handled by a class identical to DclWrapper from the Plunkr example.

I'm using Angular CLI for this project (might be relevant):

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 6.2.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.1
@angular/compiler: 2.4.1
@angular/core: 2.4.1
@angular/forms: 2.4.1
@angular/http: 2.4.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.1
@angular/router: 3.4.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.1
```

**Update**

Ok so i figured out what i did wrong, i misread the example Plunkr where it already puts the components in an array, is it possible to resolve the component based on a string? like this: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ky61O8cy3m7FYkqUzUji?p=preview)

Got it working like this, but would like to know if there's a neater solution:

```
var artwork = null;

        switch(this.type) {
            case 'Test1Component':
                artwork = Test1Component;
                break;
            case 'Test2Component':
                artwork = Test2Component;
                break;
        }

        if(artwork) {
            let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(artwork);
            this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
        }
```

Comment: Whats the exact error message?

Comment: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:42:8 caused by: No component factory found for TestComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code. What happens if you remove it from the entryComponents list?

Comment: Same error, i'll try to re-create the error in a plunker give me a min.

Comment: @BenCameron See the edit

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: In the question there's a section with 'Update',  i've provided an Plunkr.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528592/ng2-dynamically-creating-a-component-based-on-a-template

Comment: @yurzui This seems to do what i want! Will test it out later today thanks a lot!