# Create typescript type from type name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create format feature in angular where the format name is passed to a format child component.  This format component is created via

```
let componentFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(typeOfFormatComponent);
```

So, to make it configurable I need to pass the typeOfFormatComponent as a string - say - 'AddressFormatComponent'.

How do I turn the string 'AddressFormatComponent' into the type AddressFormatComponent for the resolveComponentFactory call?

Comment: Something like `const entryComponents = { 'AddressFormatComponent': AddressFormatComponent, ... `?

Comment: Ideally, the parent compent does not know about any formatters (otherwise has to be changed when a new format is introduced to add it to the entryComponents).  Hence the parent component only gets the type name as a string.

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528592/ng2-dynamically-creating-a-component-based-on-a-template/40662376#40662376

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an interface for all FormatComponents:

```
interface FormatComponents {
    AddressFormatComponent: FormatComponent;
    ...
}
resolveComponentFactory(component: keyof FormatComponents) {
    let formatComponent = FormatComponents[component]; // This will work and be typed correctly.
}
```

This allows you to have compile time checking of types by enforcing that the stings match.