# After ng production build getting miss match objects in componentFactoryResolver

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically creating a component based on a template

[More infomation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528592/ng2-dynamically-creating-a-component-based-on-a-template/40662376#40662376)

In My code

**component.ts**

```
 var factories = Array.from(this.componentFactoryResolver['_factories'].keys());
 let factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((x: any) => x.name === this.comp);
 let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
 let componentRef = this.theBody.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

**In development environment**

```
 factories===>
 ..............
  function CranchecklisttemplateComponent(cran) {
    this.cran = cran;
    this.componentlist = [];
    this.model = {};
}
.............
```

**After ng build**

```
 factories===>
     ..............
      function t(t){this.cran=t,this.componentlist=[],this.model={}}
    }
    .............
```

why function parameters are miss matched after ng build.I am using aot build false in my project.