# Angular 2 - Resolve Component Factory with a string

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

This is for the 2.1.0 Final release versions of Angular.

I'm trying to dynamically instantiate a component who's type is passed from a config JSON file. The best thing I can find is `ComponentFactoryResolver`, however all usages that I have found save one seem to be passing actual `Type` objects to the resolver.

Is there a way to get the `Type` from a string? Because presently, passing the type as a string gives me the error:

`No component factory found for MyComponent`

Relevant code:

StructureBuilder component:

```
private renderComponent(config:any) {
    let configComponents = config.components;
    if(config.hasOwnProperty('components') && configComponents.length){
        for(let i = 0, len = configComponents.length; i < len; i++){
            this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(configComponents[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

where config.components is an array of strings that use the `Type` as a value.

And in the module definition (Structure.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyComponent,
        StructureBuilder_Cmp
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        MyComponent
    ]
    //Etc...
});
```

As far as can tell with the sparse docs, this is exactly how you're supposed to do it.

If I change the dynamic string passed in from `configComponents[i]` to the actual imported type reference for `MyComponent`, it works.

So basically, the question is:
Is there a way to use `resolveComponentFactory` with strings to resolve a component, and if not, is there way to get a `Type` reference from a string value?

Comment: Do you want to pass `'MyComponent'` as string into `resolveComponentFactory`?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I mean.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115072/how-to-load-component-dynamically-using-component-name-in-angular2

Comment: @yurzui the problem with that answer is that it uses private, internal properties of the resolver. Private things like that are subject to change in future versions, so that's really not a reliable solution.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This way you have to declare something like `map = { "MyComponent": MyComponent }` and use it

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now, it's working but has overhead. I think that's just how it's going to be! 
Thanks.

Comment: If you passed in the components rather than the strings then it would obviously work.  I would change to the code to do that.  Then I would work backwards changing the code as I go back and eventually you'll find a good place to associate a name with a component (e.g. some lookup)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution for now is to do what I really wanted to avoid, which is maintaining a key/val registry.

```
let componentRegistry = {
    'SomeComp1': SomeComp1, 
    'SomeComp2': SomeComp2
}
```

And then call it with:

```
private renderComponent(config:any) {
    let configComponents = config.components;
    if(config.hasOwnProperty('components') && configComponents.length){
        for(let i = 0, len = configComponents.length; i < len; i++){
            let comp = configComponents[i];
            this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.componentRegistry[comp]);
        }
    }
}
```