# How to create a component from a variable name in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I create a component from a variable name in Angular similar to what can be achieved in Vue using [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components):

```
<component :is="myTemplate.type"></component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before Ivy**:
You should use the `ComponentFactoryResolver`. You can check out a good example of it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222579/angular-2-resolve-component-factory-with-a-string)

**With Angular Ivy**
You can use the `renderComponent` function. You can check out my blog about Ivy and dynamic component rendering here: [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-ivy-the-new-angular-engine-9cde471f42cf)

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you included the code to do both ways in your answer.

Comment: We're still at Angular 7 so I went with the first option(key-value map of available component) and it seems to work.